# Find children not having the same value for a given set of properties

Tags: sql

I retrieved data from an old software and I need to integrate it into a new one. But the data model between the old one and the new one are totally different.

The retrieved data is composed of two tables : `parent/child`. (in fact it's two `views` wrongly designed)

The parent table has 1 million rows and the child table has 2 million of rows (more or less).

To process the mapping/conversion between the old model and the new one I need to define some rules to simplify the operation.

The first one, is to check if all children of a given parent have the same value for some defined properties (if it the case I can put this value into the parent and make the children lighter and my algorithms will be simpler).

So far, I did the following request :

```
select m1.id, m2.id
from child m1
         cross join child m2
where m1.id <> m2.id
  and m1.parent_id = m2.parent_id
  and (m1.property_1 <> m2.property_1
    or m1.property_2 <> m2.property_2);
```

but I'm not 100% confident with this request and I'd like to find a request using `inner join` and `grouping by` to generate a kind of 'summarize report' of my data.

Comment: A cross join = 1 million X 2 million = 2 trillion rows.

Comment: @nicomp yep, yep that why I want to avoid the cross join. But the request provides me a result in less than 5 sec